# How to create a new InventorySku?

Tags: pipelines, sitecore-commerce, commerce-engine

I am using the IGetInventorySkuPipeline to get hold of an InventorySku object.
If I get one, then I want to modify and save it and if I don't get one (for the productId I send down the pipeline), then I want to create a new InventorySku for that product. But I don't find any pipeline for either save nor create an InventorySku.

What am I missing?

Comment: Which version of Commerce server are you using?

Comment: @Peter 8.2 version 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seem my problem was that I were using

```
CommercePipelineExecutionContext
```

and

```
Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Inventory.InventorySku
```

when I should have used

```
CommerceServer.Core.Inventory.InventoryCatalog
```

and

```
CommerceServer.Core.Inventory.InventorySku
```

Because

```
CommerceServer.Core.Inventory.InventoryCatalog
```

have a .CreateSku()
and

```
CommerceServer.Core.Inventory.InventorySku
```

have a .Save()